# Button getting cut off by div boundary

Tags: html, css, button

Working on a FAQ section for something; however, my buttons that say 'Buyers', 'Sellers', 'Docs' are getting cut off near 'Merchant Portal'. I know that my button positions are weird, which I will get to after this situation's resolved.

seeming to go under something... might be an easy fix

[image: seeming to go under something... might be an easy fix]

```
<div class="section faq" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="container" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="container" style="position:absolute; bottom: 68%; right: 21.50%; overflow:hidden;">
        <h1 style="color:whitesmoke; font-weight: 800;" class="h1 margin-left">What can we help you with?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="search_box" style="padding: 0; margin: 20% 75% 70% 65%; overflow: visible; padding-top:1%; padding-bottom:2%; margin-left:1%; margin-right:2%; margin-bottom:2%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:-5%; right:49.50%;">
        <input style="font-family:Avenir-Roman, sans-serif; color: whitesmoke; font-size: large; padding:1.50%;" id="add" type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="      Search something...">
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="position:absolute; bottom: -20%; right: -21%; width:100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <button class="button button1" style="position:relative; right:50%; top:0%; color:rgb(244, 130, 89)">Buyers</button>
        <button class="button button1" style="color:rgb(244, 130, 89)">Sellers</button>
        <button class="button button1" style="color:rgb(244, 130, 89)">Docs</button>
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="top: 85%; right: 39%; width:100%; position:absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="color:white; background-color:transparent; font-weight: 700;" class="h3 margin-left">Merchant Portal</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="top: 120%; right: 38%; width:100%; position:absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="color:white; font-weight: 700;" class="h3 margin-left">Promoted Articles</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="top: 128%; right: 34.50%; width:100%; position:absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <a href="https://www.businessinsider.com/peachpay-one-click-checkout-woocommerce-fintech-payments-bolt-fast-2021-4" target="_blank" style="color:rgb(254, 120, 62); font-size:95%; font-weight: 300;" class="h3 margin-left">PeachPay's featured in Business Insider</a>
      </div>
      <div class="container" style="top: 133%; right: 27.25%; width:100%; position:absolute; overflow: hidden;">
        <h3 style="color:rgb(242, 242, 242); font-size:95%; font-weight: 300;" class="h3 margin-left">Read about our startup and how we're changing checkout processes.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty changing the `z-index` of the button to some high number, this will make sure that the button renders on top. You can do it in a separate CSS style document, but since you are using inline CSS, you can do it like this:

```
<button style = "z-index: 10"></button>
```

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work out:( Checked other instances of z-index and made it higher than those and still didn't budge.

Comment: Maybe try moving the button?